# Where do i get the sample project for In cordova 5.0.0

Tags: android, cordova

I am new to cordova ,so i check the offical docs i fllw all instruction mentoins over their but stuck at one place
I am trying to create demo project from cmd

sudo npm install -g cordova

cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld

cd hello.

cordova platform add android.

after this nothing is happening Just show this message
Excuting "before_plaform_add" hook for all plugin.
NO version spplied.Retreving version from config.xml..

so  I am facing trouble with starting cordova is their any way to find find the cordova5.0.0.jar,cordova.js and config.xml .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have all the other dependencies installed.  As well as

```
npm install -g cordova
```

You will need to also install platform SDKs for each platform you are building, and you may need to install Java as well depending on whether or not you are building Android and what already exists on your machine.  You'll need Xcode (and to be using a Mac) to build for iOS.

Official Cordova documentation on install process is [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html).  I would strongly recommend not going with Cordova 5 unless you have to and instead using the latest Cordova 6.1.1 which you can get with:

```
npm install -g cordova@latest
```

Then verifying it:

```
cordova --version
```

Should return 6.1.1 at the time of writing.

Then try:

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
cd hello
cordova platform add ios android
cordova requirements
```

That last command "cordova requirements" should tell you if everything is installed that Cordova needs.  For example on my system:

```
cordova requirements

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed .
Android SDK: installed 
Android target: installed android-17,android-18,android-19,android-20,android-21,android-22,android-23,Google Inc.:Google APIs:17,Google Inc.:Google APIs:18,Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19,Google Inc.:Google APIs:19,Google Inc.:Google APIs (x86 System Image):19,Google Inc.:Google APIs:21,Google Inc.:Google APIs:22,Google Inc.:Google APIs:23
Gradle: installed 

Requirements check results for ios:
Apple OS X: installed darwin
Xcode: installed 7.2
ios-deploy: not installed 
ios-deploy was not found. Please download, build and install version 1.8.3 or greater from https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy into your path, or do 'npm install -g ios-deploy'
```